# Change screen resolution and size of all items when a specific application starts

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution, display-settings

My problem is that I am using a hiDPI screen with resolution 3200x1800 but when I launch some specific application, I cannot use this resolution because the text is too small.  I tried to change the resolution to 1920x1800 and changed the size of all items from 200% to 150% from Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display.  The application works fine at these settings.  Is there a way to automatically change the resolution and size to this one when I launch a specific application?

I want it to be changed when I start that specific application, and then returned to 3200x1800 when the application is closed.

Comment: Are you looking to change the system resolution setting, or could a solution like changing a setting within the application's window work?  For example, you could set a zoom setting for the window.

Comment: A zoomm setting for the window will not work i think. However, changing systems settings should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create a batch script that

1. Changes the screen resolution
2. Launches the application
3. Changes the resolution back when the application is terminated.

To do this you would want to download [Qres](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/QRes.shtml) then create a .bat script with the following:

```
@echo off
Qres.exe /x:1920 /y:1080
applicationYouWantToLaunch.exe
Qres.exe /x:3200 /y:1800
```

Comment: is there any argument to change the font size too?

Comment: I'd read up [here](http://superuser.com/questions/759498/dpi-scaling-in-windows-8-1-via-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Might try checking the 'Let me chose one scaling level for all my displays' setting in Control Panel>Appearance and Personalization>Display.  This will disable Windows' automatic per-app HiDPI scaling and allow you to set one single scaling level for all programs.  I prefer this over allowing Windows to 'guess' when it should use HiDPI scaling.  With this setting, I find less dramatic difference between HiDPI and non-HiDPI-aware apps.

I also found http://www.atrandom.iansharpe.com/setres.php